# How to solve "Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. You can switch to using Caffeine cache' warning?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caffeine, caffeine-cache

How to solve `Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it to the classpath.` warning in spring boot?

Comment: How to disable it entirely please?

Comment: @PatPatPat, just set `spring.cloud.loadbalancer.cache.enabled=false`.
See this reference chapter for details: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/3.0.2/reference/html/index.html#loadbalancer-cache-configuration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the below library in your `pom.xml`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

or in your `build.gradle`

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine
compile group: 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine', name: 'caffeine', version: '2.8.8'
```

You can replace the suitable/latest version of `caffeine`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem that this dependency solves? What is particularly wrong with the default cache? And why Spring Cloud doesn't use Caffeine by default as with many other libraries?

Comment: somebody an idea why the latest version (3.0.x) of coffeine can't be used. Otherwise the warning is logged again.

Comment: This is the right solution because it's not necessary to add spring-boot-starter-cache since it's already included in spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer.

Comment: @Toparvion As Spring itself says: "This cache implementation is useful for development and tests, it's recommended to use Caffeine cache in production.You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it and org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager to the classpath." I hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot: Adding the following dependencies in the `pom.xml` will be adequate:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below library in your `pom.xml`.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).